# how to use the regex result as var in atom editor?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I have this wrong json:

```
{
key1:"value1",
key2:"value2"
}
```

My goal is convert it to:

```
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2"
}
```

I use this regex: `^[a-z]` in atom to match the first char of key

[image]

So, as I have the first char, I need to replace it by the same but adding  a quote " at the beginning. I can't figure out how to do with atom.

**Is there an option to use any result (match) of regex as a var in the replace input text?**

Something like this:

[image]

In which {match} reference to the match result.

This will open possibilities to more complicated operations in atom editor :D.

For example: replace some occurrence **by the same** but splitted or applying some string manipulation

> I know that I can fix this json with other regex or approaches in atom, but is just a example to explain the question.

Comment: Did using `$1` or `\1` for referencing to first matching group work? if you use `(^[a-z])` of course and replace it with `"$1` or `"\1`

Comment: Thanks it works!! But $1 is not a variable because I cannot do something like this : $1.substring(0,1)  Please if you find a way to do that or not, create an answer to approve it!

Comment: Maybe if you say what you wanna do, we can propose other solutions with regex. but unfortunately i didn't use atom editor before :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [JSON requires double quotes on the keys](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp).

To use the matching string in the replacement string you have to wrap the matching pattern in parentheses to create a capture group:

```
([a-z0-9]+(?=:))
```

and then you can wrap the match in double quotes using `$1`

```
"$1"
```

[image]